# Linq Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have checked lots of posts having this error but none had this particular problem.
(Also I am new to C sharp have been a java dev)

I am getting an exception as

> System.InvalidCastException was caught

on the **table2.Field("MEME_CK")** line below in the code snippet.

There are about 3K rows in the table2, I couldn't find a way to avoid wrong casting for line **table2.Field("MEME_CK")**

Data can either be null, not present, valid or invalid. So I tried using nullable operator on the generic parameter cast. Also saw there is DBNull class that can possibly represent non existent value.

Is there a way to preprocess column data before doing "equals test" or joining in the code below ?
How can I avoid casting even after using nullable type?

Following code basically do a join on two data tables based on MemberID i.e. MEME_CK or MemeCk and creates new object with CapHeadID, MemeCk etc as fields.

```
 var query =


       (from table1 in searchResult.AsEnumerable()
         join table2 in memberInfo.AsEnumerable()
         on table1.Field<decimal?>("MemeCk") equals
            table2.Field<decimal?>("MEME_CK") 
         select new
         {
              CapHeadID = table1.Field<decimal>("CapHeadID"),

             MemeCk = table1.Field<decimal>("MemeCk"),

             Suffix = table2.Field<decimal>("MEME_SFX"), 

             Suscriber = table2.Field<string>("SBSB_ID"),

              BusinessArea = table2.Field<string>("TEAM"),

             MemberName = table2.Field<string>("MemberName"),

             WorkTypeName = table1.Field<string>("WrkName"),

             SSN = table2.Field<string>("MEME_SSN"),

             AssignedUser = table1.Field<string>("AssignedUser") 

         }).Distinct().OrderBy(a => (a.Suscriber.IsNotNil() ? 

a.Suscriber : "")).Take(3000);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what this code does.  It seems unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added the description for the code above.

Comment: What's the underlying SQL type for `MEME_CK`?

Comment: MEME_CK is basically a NUMBER(38,0) in table1 and Number in table2

Answer (score 0):

You're using `AsEnumerable` to convert the queries away from IQueryable... basically this means LINQ won't try to generate SQL code for the join, and the join will be done in C#.

With that in mind, you could try just get them as objects - like this:

```
from table1 in searchResult.AsEnumerable()
     join table2 in memberInfo.AsEnumerable()
     on table1.Field<object>("MemeCk") equals
        table2.Field<object>("MEME_CK") 
     select new...
```

I'm not sure if that will work, but it might do

Comment: Thanks it did go past the query but gave output as "Enumeration yielded no results"